# Send a POST request when user hangs up the call in Twilio Studio

Tags: twilio

I am working in Twilio Studio making an IVR survey. I need to send using a POST request the results accumulated so far to my database even if it is not completed. I don't see any transitions either that would allow for this situation

I don't see any transitions either that would allow for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is no way in Twilio Studio to detect that the user hung up. So, if you need to store partial results I would recommend using the HTTP widget to send each result back to your server. That way you will always have the latest answers from the user even if they disappear.

Comment: oh, ok thank you! That seem like a lot of HTTP calls if you have over 20 questions. Would be nice to have somekind of webhook widget or 'call ended' transition.